# module not found: Error: cant resolve 'framework7/lite-bundle'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, html-framework-7

I'm usuing framework7 in my projetc, I hae installed the latest version but when I import it in my index.js i get this error

> 

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'framework7/lite-bundle'
webpackMissingModule webpack:///./src/index.js?:6

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and found that changing the import to
`framework7/lite/bundle` worked.